# How can I deploy my second website on Elastic IP address in network interface eth 1 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, magento2, elastic-ip

I already have one Magento website running on the instance through public IP generated when creating that instance in AMAZON WEB SERVER. Now on the same instance I want to deploy another magento website. For that I have created an Elastic IP and associated it the instance and network interface also the private Ip address

Now on that Elastic IP I want my second magento website to be uploaded there. 
But I am clueless How to proceed forward 
Can you guide me like how should I access my ssh and all commands of ssh , location where to upload second website files?

Comment: Can you tell me about web server used? Apache or Nginx or other (specify name)?

Comment: Apache2 bitnami

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i am assuming that EC2 instance is same and you want to deploy second website on same.

If you are using apache as https server then you will have to create another virtual host which will server your website.
Create Virtual host inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/magentosite.conf` and then enable it and restart apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento232
    ServerAdmin support@webmaster.com
    ServerName magento232.local
    <Directory /var/www/magento232>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: but how will my second elastic IP address point to this virtual host

Comment: You don't need to have second elastic ip. Same elastic ip will work. Apache will match domain and server your website.